# ¿Como hacer que me regrese solo un valor?

Tags: sql

Estoy intentando recuperar solamente el valor 2 de esta tabla pero, por una razón que desconozco, me trae los dos valores: el 2 y el 4.

Ya intente con `GROUP BY` para que solamente me arroje un registro del `ID_CLIENTE` y sigo obteniendo la misma información me podrían apoyar gracias...

```
select * from Auditoria_enfriador as ae
    inner join Enfriador as e
    on ae.id_enfriador=e.id_enfriador
    and e.id_tipoenf=2
    where ae.fec_auditoria between'01-06-2019 00:00:00' and '30-06-2019 23:59:00' and  id_cliente=1000087
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select distinct id_cliente, sum(cantidad*puertas) from Auditoria_enfriador as ae
    inner join Enfriador as e
    on ae.id_enfriador=e.id_enfriador
    and e.id_tipoenf=2
    where ae.fec_auditoria between'01-06-2019 00:00:00' and '30-06-2019 23:59:00' and  id_cliente=1000087
  group by id_cliente
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tal vez porque los dos registros cumplen con las condiciones? las imagenes son dificiles de ver, por favor aclara los datos y los querys en texto

Comment: No se como quieres que te devuelva un registro si hay dos que cumplen con los criterios. Uno de los registros tiene cantidad 1, el otro 2. Si eliminas la cantidad de la clausula `select`y haces `group by` e va a aparecer solo uno. Mas o menos lo que has hecho en la segunda consulta.